# What is "Hyper sync flood transport error occured during last boot"

Tags: hp, reboot, error-handling

I restarted my pc after installing Windows 10 on my new Hard drive, it was fine until I restarted it 
Now I keep getting this while booting back in.
It says press F2, but it does nothing when I press it.
Is there a fix in Bios for this?
Under the Power Tab,
My NX  (no execute) is Disabled 
Virtualization Technology is Disabled.
I'm not sure about my options here.
Please help.